# Mathf.Clamp Not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pong

I am developing a clone of pong game where my paddle move on X-Axis Code for it is below:

```
void Update () {

    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    pos.x = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;
    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(pos.x,-14f,14f),-20f,0);
    transform.position = pos;

}
```

I think I am doing something stupid but I can't see it.

Comment: What *is* it doing? You say your code doesn't work correctly but you don't explain what it is currently doing

Comment: I want to say that I set boundary for my paddle on x-axis between -14 to 14 but my paddle goes out of boundary that is my problem.

Comment: Well yeah, you set the position once, and then you set it again afterwards - ignoring your entire clamping

Comment: Sorry about my question I can not explained it perfectly.. [Dharmesh](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Comment: So you mean to say transform.positon = pos is the problem?? [Dharmesh](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reassigning the position straight after clamping, ignoring that completely

```
void Update () 
{
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x,
                                                        -14f, 14f);
    transform.position = pos;
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't used unity so this makes some assumptions about the syntax being correct already.

Comment: Its working for me bro you are a genius. Thanks you. [Dharmesh](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Comment: @DharmeshKheni - No worries. Good luck with your project